# How to get the URLs of the notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, accessibilityservice

I have added an **AccessibilityService** to get the notification messages.

And I do get all the notification messages now.

My Question is : Is there any way to get the 
action url in the PendingIntent in the below code?

```
 if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) 
    {

            Parcelable data = event.getParcelableData();
            if (data instanceof Notification) {


            Notification notification = (Notification) data;
            PendingIntent nit = notification .contentIntent;
           try {
                //after i invoke nit.send, it will goto the target app and open the right news.
                nit.send();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
```

So is there any way to get the news URL from the PendingIntent?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot extract anything from a `PendingIntent`, so you cannot get the ACTION from the referenced `Intent`.